# Page size changes when visualized in Dreamweaver and in Heroku

Tags: heroku, localhost, size, dreamweaver, resolution

I developed a series of web pages, that will make up a website relying on Heroku for the database.
While coding in Dreamweaver, I kept monitoring the responsivity of the page thanks to the Developer's tool in Chrome. And everything was fine.

Now I'm visualizing the same page, with the same code, on localhost. The page size is completely different, and many of the elements are in the wrong position.

I tried to change the initial scale in the meta section. But nothing seems to change.

I don't know if code is needed or not, but this is a simplified version of the page.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Shipping</title>
    <link href="/assets/css/shipping_1440px.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 768px)" 
    href="/assets/css/shipping_768px.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 400px)" 
    href="/assets/css/shipping_400px.css" />

    </head>

    <body>



    <section id="uk_delivery">

    <h4 class="section_title" id="uk_delivery_title">
        UK delivery options
    </h4>   

    <div id="uk_container"> 


    <div class="uk_options">    

    <h6 class="uk_request">
        I want the book to be delivered at my house
     </h6>

    <h6>
         In this case you have three options:
    </h6>

    <h6>
         &#8226; Free delivery (only if you spend more than 15 £)
     <br>
         You will get the book within a week
     </h6>

    <h6>
         &#8226; Gold delivery (3.70 £)
     <br>
         You will get the book 2-3 days after the purchase
     </h6>

    <h6>
         &#8226; Platinum delivery (5.60 £)
     <br>
         You will get the book the day after the purchase
      </h6>
     </div>



    <div class="uk_options">

    <h6 class="uk_request">
         I want to pick up the book at my local Bookaholic store
          </h6>

    <h6>
         In this case you have three options:
    </h6>

    <h6>
         &#8226; Pay online and collect in store
    </h6>   

    <h6>
         &#8226; Select online and pay and collect in store
    </h6>   

    </div>      

     </div>


</section>
```

This is how I set the body properties in each CSS file

```
    body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    max-width: 1440px;
    }
```

[image: This is what I see in Dreamweaver]

[image: This is what I see on localhost]

Any advice would be useful, unfortunately I don't have enough experience to manage this problem. So thank you in advance!

Comment: Wow, Dreamweaver still exists? In any case, do you see errors in the console? If some of your stylesheets aren't loading, for example, that might explain what's going on.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get any errors.